# Get the underlying HList out from Circe

Tags: scala, shapeless, circe

Is it possible to get the underlying hlist representation out from `circe` instead of the JSON? Essentially convert a case class to an HList

Note: I am aware that this can be achieved directly with shapeless, I would like to try `circe's` macro based parser, as I ran into performance issues with shapeless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that there is any "underlying hlist representation out from `circe`"?

What `circe` does is [parsing](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/master/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Parser.scala#L6) a `String` into JSON, introducing type classes [Decoder](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/master/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Decoder.scala#L17) and [Encoder](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/master/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Encoder.scala#L18)

```
trait Encoder[A] extends Serializable { self =>
  def apply(a: A): Json
//...
}

trait Decoder[A] extends Serializable { self =>
  def apply(c: HCursor): Decoder.Result[A]
//...
}
```

and [deriving](https://github.com/circe/circe/tree/master/modules/shapes/src/main/scala/io/circe/shapes) these type classes using `shapeless`. For example this means that if we have `Decoder[H]` and `Decoder[T]` then we have `Decoder[H :: T]`. But there is no underlying `circe` representation for a case class other than [Json](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/master/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Json.scala#L15).

`circe` doesn't convert a case class to an `HList`, `shapeless` does.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought it'd use hlist as an intermediate representation.